# How does $x_{n+1}\ge x_n\land y_{y+1}\le y_n \land \lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-y_n) = 0\implies \lim x_n = \lim y_n$ and both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ denote two sequences. The sequences are given such that:
>   $$
> x_{n+1} \ge x_n \\
> y_{n+1} \le y_n \\
> \lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-y_n) = 0
> $$
>   Prove that both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent and:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n
> $$

I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof. I've started with inspecting the relations between $x_n$ and $y_n$:
$$
x_{n+1} \ge x_n \\
y_{n+1} \le y_n \\ \iff
\\
x_{n+1} \ge x_n \\
-y_{n+1} \ge -y_n
$$
From which it follows that:
$$
x_{n+1} - y_{n+1} \ge x_n - y_n \tag 1
$$

Denote $z_n = x_n - y_n$, then by $(1)$ it follows that $z_n$ is a monotonically increasing sequence:
$$
z_{n+1} \ge z_n
$$
By monotone convergence theorem it follows that if $\lim z_n = 0$ and $z_{n+1} \ge z_n$ then $z_n \le 0$. Also $z_n$ is convergent hence bounded:
$$
m \le z_n \le M
$$
By the fact that $z_n < 0$ it follows that $x_n < y_n$.
The problem is i do not see how to combine those facts in order to show what is requested in the problem statement. Seems like the problem may be reduced to using MCT for $x_n$ and $y_n$ alone or use the properties of $\limsup$, $\liminf$ or somehow use the triangular inequality but i do not see how.

What is a proper way to achieve that?

Comment: Hint: Can you use $x_n<y_n$ to show that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded?

Comment: @Uncountable $\lim(x_n - y_n) = \lim (n - (-n)) \ne 0$ so it violates the initial conditions.

Comment: Yes, roman, I realised that as soon as I posted it. I apologise.

Comment: @SmileyCraft I would appreciate if you could elaborate on this. Intuitively the statement is true however I don't see where the boundedness of $x_n$ comes from

Comment: @roman By induction $y_n\leq y_1$, so $y_1$ is an upper bound of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Thank you! I think i've got the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed as follows, without reference to the “nested intervals lemma” (which is essentially equivalent to what you want to prove):

As you already observed, $z_n = x_n - y_n$ is increasing, with $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = 0$. It follows that $x_n \le y_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Then 
$$
 x_n \le x_{n+1} \le y_{n+1} \le y_1 \quad (n \in \Bbb N)
$$
so that the sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing and bounded above, and therefore convergent: $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists.

Similarly,
$$
 y_n \ge y_{n+1} \ge x_{n+1} \ge x_1 \quad (n \in \Bbb N)
$$
implies that $(y_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$ exists as well.

Finally  (since both limits exits),
$$
0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n
$$
so that the limits are equal.

Comment: Nice approach, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a hint by @SmileyCraft we might show that $x_n$ is bounded and increasing hence convergent. Consider the following inequality:
$$
x_n \le y_n
$$
Since $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing we have that:
$$
x_n \le x_{n+1}
$$

By $y_n$ is monotonically decreasing:
$$
y_{n+1} \le y_{n}
$$

Expanding that further and using the fact $x_n \le y_n$ we may obtain:
$$
x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_{n-1} \le x_{n} \le x_{n+1} \le y_{n+1} \le y_n \le y_{n-1} \le \cdots \le y_2 \le y_1
$$

Which a set of nested intervals. By the Nested intervals lemma and the fact that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n - y_n) = 0
$$
we know that there is a single point  $L$ which belongs to all of the intervals. By monotonicity of $x_n$ and $y_n$ this point appears to be the limit for both sequences. So by this $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge and:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n =L
$$

Comment: I hope this is correct